# C# multiple comboboxes

Tags: c#, combobox

I am writing a program that has two tabs on it.  On the first tab the user must enter information about an account(account number, name, address, and phone #).  They must also enter investment information(ID,Name,symbol, and shares).  Whenever the user clicks on the add customer button, the name of the person goes to a combobox on the second tab.  Whenever the user enters information about the investments the name of the investment goes into a listbox on the first tab.  The issue I face is that whenever i select an account from the combobox on the second tab, i need an investment combobox to show only the entries for that account and not everysingle one entered while the program has been up.  I need to choices from the Investment combobox to be determined by the selection in the customer combobox.

here's the first tab[image]

and here's the second
[image]

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i do not know how to base the Investment combobox options depending on the selected account from the client combobox.  In the first tab the user enters the #,name,address,and phone number and then fills in the investment information. Everytime the user clicks either add stock or add mutual fund the account goes into the respective listbox.  I need the investment combobox to display the investments from the lstbox depending on the account selected in the client combobox.

Comment: Your design makes it complicated. Try to separate the customer management form and the investment transaction.

Comment: What if my mouse skills aren't precise enough to allow me to hit the 'add customer' button? Sorry couldn't resist... smack me...

Comment: Hitting the add customer button only adds the client information to the first combobox.  When i click it i want it to add the name to the client to the first combobox and then I will have options for the second combobox as well

Answer (score 2):

Hook up a function to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox.  When it runs, you can fill up the other ComboBox.

Comment: I still dont know how to tie the two comboboxes together though?

Comment: James - that does tie them together. Click the combo you want controlling the other. Then in properties, look for 'events' and pick the SelectedIndexChanged event. It will add a handler and insert an empty function. This is what he means by 'hook up a function'. Now you can put code in the function, (1) clear the subordinate combo box (2) loop thru all the items entered and add just the appropriate ones.

Comment: So under that SelectedIndexChanged would I also put the code to display all that information in the appropriate textboxes?

Comment: Yes.  Try that.  If it doesn't work, try something else.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: @Steve, James has been [told this multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239392/c-sharp-combobox-options-dependent-on-another-combobox). He apparently isn't wanting to listen (or accept answers he's given, either, or even upvote them for the effort).