# C# combobox options dependent on another combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am working on a program in which a combobox's options are dependent on another combobox's selected option.  The selected item from the first combobox chooses which options are in the second combobox.  Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the button that adds the information to the first combobox

```
    try
        {
            CustomerAccount aCustomerAccount = new CustomerAccount(txtAccountNumber.Text, txtCustomerName.Text,
            txtCustomerAddress.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text);
            account.Add(aCustomerAccount);

            cboClients.Items.Add(aCustomerAccount.GetCustomerName());
            ClearText();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure every text box is filled in!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

And here is the selectedIndex for the first combobox.

```
 private void cboClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CustomerAccount custAccount = account[cboClients.SelectedIndex] as CustomerAccount;
        if (custAccount != null)
        {
            txtAccountNumberTab2.Text = custAccount.GetAccountNumber();
            txtCustomerNameTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerName();
            txtCustomerAddressTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerAddress();
            txtCustomerPhoneNumberTab2.Text = custAccount.GetCustomerPhoneNo();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from ? is it all in one list ? what is the first one filtering on ?

Comment: What is the data that you are trying to add to the 2nd ComboBox?

Comment: The names of the Investments put into either listbox

Comment: Where are you pulling that information from?

Comment: its being stored in an ArrayList

Comment: Everything in one list or is it unique for each customer account?

Comment: Everything is on one ArrayList called account

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# multiple comboboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239190/c-sharp-multiple-comboboxes)

Answer (score 6):

Add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler for the first `ComboBox`. Use it to clear the content of the second `ComboBox` and populate it with the related items:

```
public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("Item {0}", i.ToString()));
    }
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      comboBox2.Items.Add(String.Format("Item_{0}_{1}", 
                          comboBox1.SelectedItem, i.ToString()));
    }
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thats the thing though, I'm not quite sure how to reference what is being put in the listboxes.

Comment: I've answered the question you asked. Are you now changing it to a new one (how to access `custAccount` once one is selected)? If so, that's a separate question. (Also, your edit doesn't indicate exactly what you want to put into the second combobox. Your new question should address that as well.)

Comment: I'm just not sure what the code would be under the selectedIndexChanged that would grab the listbox items and put them in the second combobox

Comment: As I said, you haven't said what you want to appear in the second combobox, so I don't know how I'm supposed to help you. :) Your code above for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event doesn't try to put anything into a second combobox at all; you're assigning values to `txt<something>Tab2.Text` with no indication of what those are, and your question mentioned a second combobox based on the selection in a first combobox. Stop, regroup to figure out what additional information you want to ask (this question has been answered), and post a new question about doing the other thing you want to now do.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion.  What i would like explained is how to populate the second combobox with items in a listbox from the first tab.  The first combobox is a sort of account overview.  It contains the name of a person who just made an account.  When the user selects a name in the first combobox i would like the second combobox to be populated with the items from the listboxes on the first tab which include investment information entered by the user.  Many accounts can be made on the first tab and each item in the first combobox should display options in the 2nd cbobox specific to it.

Comment: James, I've said (now 3 time) that this isn't what your original question asked, and what you now want is a new question. You need to post that new question with details of what you're putting into the first comboBox and what you're expecting to see in the second one when the first one is changed. The question you asked here has been answered as asked; changing it after the fact to a different question is inappropriate. Post a **new** question that provides the details I've been trying to pry out of you here, and we'll get you an answer to that question (if you tell us what you really want).